# how to apply css to list tooltips using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I would like to apply css to my tooltips, I want the background of my tooltips to be in gray and the text to be in bold.

the problem is that I really don't know how to do it especially since I have a list with lots of options and each option has its own tooltip, I want to apply css to its tooltips which are in the options of my list .

here is the code from my list:

```
<select id="worker" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedExportWorker" [formControl]="workerForm.controls['selectedExportWorker']" (ngModelChange)="selectWorker()">
   <option [ngValue]="blankObject"></option>
   <option *ngFor="let worker of workerExportList; index as i" [ngValue]="worker" class="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{info_bulle_export[i]}}">{{worker.label}}</option>
</select>
```

here is the result of the tooltip I currently have :
[image: tooltip]

and here is an example of a tooltip i want to get :
[image: tooltip 2]

here is all my .html code:

```
<div class="workers center">
    <p-dialog #dialog [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="450" responsive="true" closable="true" id="loading-panel" appendTo="body">
        <p-header style="color: #FB864F;font-size: 18px;">
            Worker en cours d'exécution ...
        </p-header>
        <img style="width: 200px; margin-left: 100px;" src="assets/images/panda_face.gif" />
    </p-dialog>
    <div class="box">
        <form [formGroup]="workerForm" id="workerForm">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h1 class="box-title"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Workers </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="worker" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Worker: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="worker" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedExportWorker" [formControl]="workerForm.controls['selectedExportWorker']"
                            (ngModelChange)="selectWorker()">
                            <option [ngValue]="blankObject"></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let worker of workerExportList; index as i" [ngValue]="worker" class="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{info_bulle_export[i]}}">{{worker.label}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div><br/><br/>
                <div class="form-group" [hidden]="isHiddenCatalogue">
                    <label for="catalog" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Catalogue: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="catalog" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCatalog" [formControl]="workerForm.controls['selectedCatalog']">
                            <option [ngValue]="blankObject">{{blankObject.code}}</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let catalog of catalogues" [ngValue]="catalog">{{catalog.code}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" [hidden]="isHiddenMappingSystem">
                    <label for="catalog" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Système de mapping: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="catalog" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedMappingSystem" [formControl]="workerForm.controls['selectedMappingSystem']">
                            <option [ngValue]="blankObjectMS">{{blankObjectMS.code}}</option>
                            <option [ngValue]="blanckObjectMSAllInAZip">{{blanckObjectMSAllInAZip.code}}</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let mappingSystem of mappingSystems" [ngValue]="mappingSystem">{{mappingSystem.code}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer form_settings">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right submit side" (click)="executer()">Executer</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Progression de l'exécution </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <p-progressBar [value]="value"></p-progressBar>
            <div class="workerSuccess" id="workerSuccess"><h4>Le worker a été importé avec succès !</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="box loading">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Workers en cours d'exécution </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body"></div>
    </div> -->

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h2 class="box-title"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i> Fichiers présents sur le serveur</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="PrimeTableDiv box-body">
            <p-toolbar>
                <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left form_settings toolbar">
                    <button pButton class="submit side toolbar" label="Supprimer" icon="fa-trash" (click)="confirmDelete()"></button>
                    <button pButton class="submit side toolbar" label="Télecharger" icon="fa-download" (click)="downloadFile()"></button>
                    <button pButton class="submit side toolbar" label="rafraichir" icon="fa-sync" (click)="refresh()"></button>
                </div>
            </p-toolbar>
            <!-- <p-tree [value]="filesTree2" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFile" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)" (onNodeUnselect)="nodeUnselect($event)" -->
            <p-tree [value]="filesTree2" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFile" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)"
                [style]="{'width':'100%'}">
                </p-tree>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p-confirmDialog width="425" appendTo="body"></p-confirmDialog>
```

here is all my .html code if you need:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, ResponseContentType, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from './../../../../environments/environment';
import { ExportService } from './../../exportDirectoryBrowsing/export.service';
import { sideMenuComponent } from './../../../layout/side-menu-component/side-menu.component';
import { WorkerParameterInfo } from './../workerParameterInfo';
import { WorkerExport } from './WorkerExport';
import { MappingSystemService } from './../../mappingSystem/mapping-system.service';
import { CatalogService } from './../../catalogue/Catalog.service';
import { Catalog } from './../../catalogue/Catalog';
import { MappingSystem } from './../../mappingSystem/MappingSystem';
import { MappingContext } from './../../mappingContext/MappingContext';
import { Component,  ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { LazyLoadEvent, ConfirmationService, TreeNode, Message } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { WorkersService } from '../worker.service';
import { SharedService } from './../../../shared.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { DialogModule, Dialog } from 'primeng/components/dialog/dialog';
import {ProgressSpinnerModule} from 'primeng/components/progressspinner/progressspinner';
import { Timeouts } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { $$iterator } from 'rxjs/internal/symbol/iterator';



@Component({
    selector: 'export',
    templateUrl: './export.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./../../global.css'],
    providers: [WorkersService, ConfirmationService]
})
export class ExportComponent {

    info_bulle_export=["Exporte les données des catalogues du contexte de mapping en cours au format XML",

    "Exporte les données de mapping du contexte de mapping en cours au format XML",


    "Exporte dans le même fichier XML les données catalogues et mapping par système de mapping, peut exporter dans une archive de fichiers XML tous les systèmes de mapping du contexte en cours",
    "Exporte le contexte de mapping en cours au format zip archivant les données catalogues dans un fichier XML et les données mapping dans un autre fichier XML",



    ];
    value = 0;
    workerForm: FormGroup;
    selectedExportWorker: WorkerExport;
    selectedMappingContext: MappingContext;
    selectedMappingSystem: MappingSystem;
    selectedCatalog: Catalog;
    catalogues: Catalog[] = [];
    workerExportList: WorkerExport[] = [];
    mappingSystems: MappingSystem[] = [];
    blankObject: Catalog = new Catalog(0, 'TOUS', 'TOUS', null);
    blankObjectMS: MappingSystem = new MappingSystem(0, 'TOUS', null, null, null, null, null);
    blanckObjectMSAllInAZip : MappingSystem = new MappingSystem(100, 'TOUS DANS UN ZIP', null, null, null, null, null);
    isHiddenCatalogue = false;
    isHiddenMappingSystem = false;
    filesTree2: TreeNode[] = [];
    selectedFile: TreeNode;
    msgs: Message[] = [];
    display: Boolean = false;
    response: Response;

    @ViewChild('dialog') dialog: DialogModule;
    @ViewChild('spinner') spinner: ProgressSpinnerModule;



    constructor(private workersService: WorkersService, private api: SharedService,
        fb: FormBuilder, private catalogService: CatalogService, private mappingSystemService: MappingSystemService,
        private exportService: ExportService, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private http: Http) {

        this.workerExportList.push(new WorkerExport('catalogueExport', 'Export des catalogues'));

        this.workerExportList.push(new WorkerExport('mappingExport', 'Export des mappings'));


        this.workerExportList.push(new WorkerExport('koalaExport', 'Export koala'));
        this.workerExportList.push(new WorkerExport('pamdaExport', 'Export pamda'));




        this.workerForm = fb.group({
            'selectedExportWorker': '',
            'selectedCatalog': this.blankObject,
            'selectedMappingSystem': this.blankObjectMS
        })



        this.selectedCatalog = this.blankObject;
        this.selectedMappingSystem = this.blankObjectMS;

        this.api.getDataMappingContext().subscribe(_sharingData => {
            this.selectedMappingContext = _sharingData;
            if (_sharingData) {
                this.exportService.getByMappingCOntext(_sharingData.id).subscribe(data => {
                    this.createTree(data, this.filesTree2, null);
                    console.log(this.filesTree2);
                });
            }
        });
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        localStorage.removeItem('mapping');
        localStorage.removeItem('page');
        this.api.getDataMappingContext().subscribe(mappingContext => {
            if (mappingContext != null) {
                this.selectedMappingContext = mappingContext;
                this.mappingSystemService.getByMappingContext(this.selectedMappingContext.id).subscribe(data => this.mappingSystems = data);
                this.catalogService.getCatalogByMappingContext(this.selectedMappingContext.id).subscribe(data => this.catalogues = data);
            }
        });
    }

    exportCatalogue() {
       return this.workersService.exportCatalogue(new WorkerParameterInfo()).subscribe();
    }

    selectWorker() {
        this.value = 0;
        if (this.selectedExportWorker != null && (
            this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'catalogueExport' ||
            this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'dataExport')) {
            this.isHiddenCatalogue = false;
        } else {
            this.isHiddenCatalogue = true ;
        }

        if (this.selectedExportWorker != null && this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'koalaExport') {
            this.isHiddenMappingSystem = false;
        } else {
            this.isHiddenMappingSystem = true;
        }
    }

    executer() {
        this.value = 60;
        let workerParameterInfo = new WorkerParameterInfo();
        workerParameterInfo.currentMappingContext = this.selectedMappingContext.id;
        workerParameterInfo.disabledByUser = false;
        if (this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'catalogueExport') {
            this.display = true;
            workerParameterInfo.catalogueIdOrALL = this.selectedCatalog.id.toString();
            this.workersService.exportCatalogue(workerParameterInfo).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                console.log('response catalogueExport :', res);
                this.display = false;
                this.refresh();
            });
        } else if (this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'mappingExportV1_0') {
            this.display = true;
            this.workersService.exportMappingV10(workerParameterInfo).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                this.display = false;
                this.refresh();
            });
        } else if (this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'mappingExport') {
            this.display = true;
            this.workersService.exportMapping(workerParameterInfo).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                this.display = false;
                this.refresh();
            });
        } else if (this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'koalaExport') {
            this.display = true;
            workerParameterInfo.mappingSystemIdOrALL = this.selectedMappingSystem.id.toString();
            console.log('koala workerParameterInfo :', workerParameterInfo.mappingSystemIdOrALL);
            this.workersService.exportKoala(workerParameterInfo).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                console.log(res);
                this.display = false;
                this.refresh();
            });
        }  else if (this.selectedExportWorker.code === 'pamdaExport') {
            this.display = true;
            this.workersService.exportPamda(workerParameterInfo).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                this.display = false;
                this.refresh();
            });
        }  
        this.value = 90;
        this.refresh();
        this.value = 100;
    }

    createTree(data: any[], tree: TreeNode[], parent: TreeNode) {
        // console.log('creating Tree From: ', data);

        data.forEach(dir => {
            let treeNode: TreeNode = {
                label: '',
                data: '',
                children: [],
                leaf: false,
                expandedIcon: '',
                collapsedIcon: '',
                icon: '',
                expanded: true,
                parent: {}
            };

            if (dir.leaf === false) {
                treeNode.label = dir.label;
                treeNode.expandedIcon = 'fa-folder-open';
                treeNode.collapsedIcon = 'fa-folder';
                treeNode.parent = parent;
                this.createTree(dir.children, treeNode.children, treeNode)
                tree.push(treeNode);
            } else {
                treeNode.label = dir.label;
                treeNode.leaf = true;
                treeNode.data = dir.data;
                treeNode.parent = parent;
                if (treeNode.label.endsWith('zip')) {
                    treeNode.icon = 'fa-file-archive';
                } else if (treeNode.label.endsWith('xml')) {
                    treeNode.icon = 'fa-file-code';
                } else if (treeNode.label.endsWith('xls')) {
                    treeNode.icon = 'fa-file-excel';
                } else if (treeNode.label.endsWith('txt')) {
                    treeNode.icon = 'fa-file';
                } else {
                    treeNode.icon = 'fa-file';
                }
                tree.push(treeNode);
            }
        });
    }


    confirmDelete() {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet objet?',
            header: 'Confirmation de suppression',
            icon: 'fa fa-trash',
            accept: () => {
                this.deleteFile();
            }
        });
    }

    nodeSelect(event) {
        if (event.node.leaf === false) {
            this.selectedFile = null;
        }
    }

    deleteFile() {
        this.exportService.delete(this.selectedFile.data).subscribe(() => {
            this.selectedFile.parent.children.splice(this.selectedFile.parent.children.findIndex(
                child => child.data === this.selectedFile.data), 1);
            this.showSuccess('Fichier supprimé avec succès');
        });
    }


    downloadFile() {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob, // dont forget to import the enum
            // In case you get Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http/src/enums', just use 3 instead ex 'responseType:3'
        });
        let workerParameterInfo = new WorkerParameterInfo();
        workerParameterInfo.pathFile = this.selectedFile.data;

        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(workerParameterInfo);
        this.http.post(`${environment.url.base}${environment.url.pamda.downloadFile}`, bodyString, requestOptions).subscribe(res => {
            FileSaver.saveAs(res.blob(), this.selectedFile.label)
        });

    }


    refresh() {
        this.filesTree2 = [];
        if (this.selectedMappingContext) {
            this.exportService.getByMappingCOntext(this.selectedMappingContext.id).subscribe(data => {
                this.createTree(data, this.filesTree2, null);
                // console.log(this.filesTree2);
            })
        }
    }

    showError() {
        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Message d\'erreur', detail: 'Vous ne pouvez pas supprimer ce catalogue' });
    }

    showSuccess(details) {
        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Succès', detail: details });
    }

}
```

and this is my all css code :

```
    .tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;

}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #555;

  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline-color: #FB864F;
  }
*:focus{
 outline-color: #FB864F;
}

*:hover{
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

input[type="text"]:focus{
outline-color: #FB864F;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{ font-size: 175%;
  color: #F55000;
  margin: 0 0 8pt 0;
  padding: 8pt 0 3pt 0;}

h2
{ font-size: 175%;
  color: #F55000;}
h3
{ font-size: 140%;
  color: #FB864F;
  margin-left: 8pt;}
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: You are using a `<select>` field, are you somehow converting it to some custom html structure (Like select2 & jQuery would do)? If not, then your requirement is not possible. You can't have html tooltip on option elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

.html

```
<div class="custom-tooltip">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
    </button>
</div>
```

.css

```
::ng-deep .custom-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:bold;
}
::ng-deep .custom-tooltip .arrow::before {
   border-top-color: #dddddd;
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7eynjk?embed=1&file=app/tooltip-basic.css)**

Comment: I added my css file in the description can you please help me and see if something that I have defined in my css is blocking

Comment: ::ng-deep is important. It is used to overwrite child components css

Comment: I have already done this but it does not work.

here is what i did: <option  *ngFor="let worker of workerExportList; index as i" [ngValue]="worker" class="custom-tooltip"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{info_bulle_export[i]}}">{{worker.label}}</option>

Comment: and I also put this css code : ::ng-deep .custom-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: red;
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:bold;
}
::ng-deep .custom-tooltip .arrow::before {
   border-top-color: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this!

```css
[data-title] {
  outline: red dotted 1px; /*optional styling*/
  margin-top: 100px; /*optional styling*/
  font-size: 30px; /*optional styling*/
  
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-title]:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
[data-title]:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 8px solid transparent;    
  border-top: 8px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Styling tooltip</h1>
<span data-title="Some text for tooltip">Hover me</span>
```

Comment: Please, add some comments about your code and how does it answers the question.

Comment: Use data-title attribute on the element you want to show styled tooltip
You can use attribute name as your desire instead of data-title